# Why are websockets disabled in the browser

Tags: meteor

Meteor is awesome, but it looks like it uses long polling in the browser instead of real websockets.

Meteor uses sockjs, right? Are sockets disabled explicitly? (read it somewhere here). what's the reason for it?

Tanks a lot
Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Since [Meteor 0.6.3.1](http://meteor.com/blog/2013/05/15/meteor-063-websockets-mongodb-24-coffee-162-synthetic-tap-events) websockets are enabled by default in numerous browsers.

**Previous answer:**
For some reason I can't find the source (think it was on the mailinglist, but can't find it there), but from the top of my head:

They are explictly disabled due to compatibility issues with various browsers.

Comment: Thanks. I'd love to know what these problems are. I thought websockets are well supported in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets are (were?) disabled in meteor due to the fact that they crashed Chrome when Inspector was enabled. That's it.

Comment: Hi, I browsed the sources and found a comment explaining it https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/stream/stream_client.js#L306-L307. For now I activated sockets locally. The file can be found in `.meteor/local/build/static/packages/stream` (relatively to your projects root)